# How to create an undulating fabric texture using inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Could someone please provide guidance on creating the following type of texture:

[image: picture showing wave nature in a silk cloth]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is clearly a 'gimme the codez' type question. We are not a 'request a tutorial' site, we're a 'help you when you get stuck following the tutorial' site.

Comment: You realize that is a photo, right?

Comment: Hi, I just posted this photo to convey my idea clearly. Anyway  the given answer by Billy Kerr is helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Better to take a photo of some real undulating fabric - the example you posted is a photograph - a raster image. Inkscape is a vector image editor, best suited to line art/logos - not photographic realism.

However it is kind of possible using the gradient mesh feature now available in Inkscape.

Example of Gradient Mesh

[image: Example of Gradient Mesh in Inkscape]